# How can I get Ingress invites?

Tags: ingress

What's the easiest, fastest, surest way to score an Ingress invite, or is the signup at the Niantic site the best bet?

Comment: Invites to what?  Ingress?

Comment: Highly recommend you take a peek at our FAQ http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq Contains all the info ya should need to get started.. as it stands right now I am not sure if your question is anything more than "See how Canadian I am?" and I have no idea how to answer that.

Comment: Pete, the idea is that questions here are write-once, read-many. Try and make your questions not just about yourself, but about the generic case.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just assumed people would understand that I do know you can just go ahead and ask for one on the Niantic signup page (a poor assumption, I know). I should have been more clear-- I want to know if there were a shorter, more immediate route to an invite than simply signing up and waiting. I've edited my question for clarity.

Comment: The question post-editing is actually a valid concern, shame that it got so many negative votes due to subjective phrasing earlier :(. @PeteRockwell: We usually expect anything already tried to be in the question, else its assumed the asker would not know about it (e.g. the signup link).

Answer (score 5):

Define an easy way, I know some people who just sign up for an invite at [Niantic Labs](http://www.nianticproject.com/) and got their invite. As far as I know they constantly send new invites through several channels, and as the game gets massive, I guess the number of sing up invites sent will only get bigger.

It is also a lot of fun to make a fuzz :)

**Update:** There are several ways to get an invite to ingress:

1. Promote ingress in G+ or your personal blog (make it creative and fun), send a link to [+Niantic Project](https://plus.google.com/+NianticProject/posts) and [+Brandon Badger](https://plus.google.com/114800310452543164210/posts) - this method worked pretty well before
2. Follow ingress and niantic labs twitter, e.g. [@IngressNews](https://twitter.com/IngressNews), they give out invites regularly, sometimes they make trivia contests in irc, or refer to other sources like podcasts where some invites are given away - a fast way to get an invite but quite unreliable (you have to win the contest)
3. Sign up for an invite at [Niantic Labs](http://www.nianticproject.com/)
4. Have a friend at google or niantic lab

Comment: That's what I'm wondering-- You say they send invites through several channels. I want to know the fastest and most reliable of those channels. I know I can just wait it out, but if there's something I can do or somewhere I can go to get one sooner, I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: It took me about 4-5 hours of twitter searching. Many people have extra invites and ask if anyone wants them. Be the first to respond and you might get one.

Answer (score 2):

In order of speed to get an invite:

1. The easiest and fastest way, would be to have a **friend at Google** who can help you get on the internal signup list for invites (or if you know someone at Niantic Labs, they could probably just invite you directly).
2. **Create some artwork or graphics related to Ingress** and share that on G+ to [#Ingress](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts) and #IngressInvite tags. This is probably the best way in general, and you don't need amazing photo editing skills, just a neat idea and pre-existing image are enough - see some of the submissions that got invited.
3. Sign up for the **general waiting list** at the website.

---

### Ingress Artwork

This seems to be a popular method to catch attention of the Ingress devs, so I will elaborate on it further.

**Sharing the picture**

Make sure you share it to the #ingress and #ingressinvite tag. Most people also specifically add some of the Ingress developers, Brandon Badger, Brian Rose etc. ... check the successful re-shared posts in #ingress who got the invite.

**Artwork Features**

This is just my observation of common traits in the accepted graphics, I don't know of a particular 'acceptance criteria' as it is basically a question of whether Niantic sees & likes it.

- **Incorporate** the Niantic, Enlightened or Resistance **logos**
- Could also use **green or blue** filters or coloring (reason: Enlightened faction is green and Resistance is blue in the Ingress UI)
- Using public domain or **free license images** and altering them seems to be ok
- **Don't use images with people** in them (portraits of historical figures seem fine). The only pic I see posted with a person, is a self-photo of the poster ... in general I expect Niantic will steer clear of model release issues.
- Clever **stories about how Ingress has been around for a long time** (by editing in the logo to ancient sites, famous art etc.) seem to be received favorably.

Comment: Update: It seems Niantic will shortly be giving some invites to L6+ players (I think they are finally enabling the 'Recruit' button). So the best method may be just to ask your local agents - not editing answer till we have more details & its live.

Answer (score 1):

All of the tricks mentioned in above answers are what everyone says. But if you want to have the activation code faster, then you can try this method which worked for me.

The trick is to periodically check `#Ingress` and `#Ingress-Invite` for an Activation code. People generally share spare activation code there. I guessed this when I saw various old and already redeemed activation code there. So I just waited for few hours and Bingo!! I got the activation code.

Just to mention I bought my Android phone on 1st Jan and got the activation code on 5th Jan. Nothing else can be faster than that. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Almost all big cities have an Ingress Google Plus Community interested in recruiting new members. For instance, San Diego, CA has:

- [Resistance](https://plus.google.com/communities/109099732859455777650): https://plus.google.com/communities/109099732859455777650
- [Enlightened](https://plus.google.com/105570410828145668915/posts/24xqX5FYD8Q): https://plus.google.com/105570410828145668915/posts/24xqX5FYD8Q

Decide which side you're on and join one of the communities for the city closest you by clicking the `Ask to join` button or following the instructions on the community page. You should be approved fairly quickly. Then you'll be able to ask them for an invite. One of the goals of those communities is to recruit new members quickly so you should receive and invite soon after you ask for one.